# Mostrar los divisores de un nro. ingresado por teclado. El nro. ingresado debe estar comprendido entre 1 y 99 (validarlo). JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, html, bucle-for, validación, while

Tengo que realizar una actividad y he quedado un poco trabado.
utilizando for while o do while
Realizar un programa que muestre los divisores de un numero ingresado, este numero debe estar entre 1 y 99 (validarlo)
por ejemplo

```
        
        si se ingresa el 25, los divisores son: 1, 5, 25.

        si se ingresa el 12, los divisores son: 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 12.
```

he realizado este pero no funciona.

```
<HTML>
     <HEAD>
        <TITLE> Divisores de un numero </TITLE>
     </HEAD>
    <BODY>
         <SCRIPT>
               var NUM_1, i, divisores, conc='';
               
               NUM_1 = parseFloat(prompt("Ingrese un numero: " , "[Entre 1 y 99]));
               
               for (i=1 ; 1<=NUM_1 ; i++)
               {
                   while (NUM_1<1 || NUM_1>99 ) {
                     if (NUM_1%1==0)
                         conc=conc+''+1
                   }
               }
               document.write("los divisores del numero" +NUM_1 "son" +s+"." ;
               
               </SCRIPT>
               </BODY>
               </HTML>
```

Espero que me puedan ayudar!
Gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var NUM_1 = 0,
  i,
  divisores,
  conc = "";

// 1. La cadena del prompt no está bien formada
//NUM_1 = parseFloat(prompt("Ingrese un numero: " , "[Entre 1 y 99]));

// 4. la validación debe ser durante el ingreso del número
while (NUM_1 < 1 || NUM_1 > 99) {
  NUM_1 = parseFloat(prompt("Ingrese un numero:  , [Entre 1 y 99]"));
}

// 2. La condición final del for está incorrecta
// tiene un 1 en lugar de una i
//for (i=1 ; 1<=NUM_1 ; i++)

for (i = 1; i <= NUM_1; i++) {
  // 5. Se ha usado el número 1 en lugar de la variable i
  // if (NUM_1 % 1 == 0) conc = conc + "" + 1;
  
  if (NUM_1 % i == 0) conc = conc + "" + i;
}
// 3. Falta el paréntesis de cierre
// falta un signo + para concatenar
// la variable s no existe
//document.write("los divisores del numero" +NUM_1 "son" +s+".") ;

document.write("los divisores del numero" + NUM_1 + "son" + conc + ".");
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por responder! funciona perfecto, y pude ver mis errores. espero seguir aprendiendo. Saludos!